# C# trackbar mciSendString

Tags: c#, mci

I'm writing a CD Audio player program using MCI, but I can't show the progress of the audio file on a trackbar.

Does anyone know how?

Note that I must use [`mciSendString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757161) to get the track length.

Answer (score 0):

From [Simple MCI Player - CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/63094/Simple-MCI-Player), slightly altered:

```
public int GetCurrentPosition()
{
    String command = "status MediaFile position";
    error = mciSendString(command, returnData, 
                          returnData.Capacity, IntPtr.Zero);
    return error == 0 ? int.Parse(returnData.ToString()) : 0;
}

public int GetSongLenght()
{
    if (IsPlaying())
    {
        String command = "status MediaFile length";
        error = mciSendString(command, returnData, returnData.Capacity, IntPtr.Zero);
        return error == 0 ? int.Parse(returnData.ToString()) : 0;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: thx but my question here is about the trackbar...i don't know how to show the track progress on it...

Comment: @user1740616 call `GetCurrentPosition` to get the current position of the file, then set the trackbar's value to that.

Comment: how about eventhandler? i think i need that too?

Comment: @user1740616 what makes you think so? Does MCI raise events?

Comment: ok so after i get the current position i pass it to trackbars value ok i have done that,but its still not moving with track..so i think i need an eventhandler...

Comment: @user1740616 you don't need an eventhandler, because there is no event to be handled. You could use a timer that polls the track location every second or so.

Comment: yea thats the problem ...how? lol sorry its just that i didnt use c# in a long time...

Comment: thx alot but i already tried that..well i think i'll try and figure it out myself from here.thx again

Comment: @CodeCaster How do I convert the number returned from `GetSongLenght()` to seconds?

Answer (score 0):

In VB I did this inside a Timer Tick Sub...easy peasy really...

rem audio is the mcisendstring thingy
rem TotalLength is total seconds of current track

```
    Dim PlayPosition As Long = 0

    PlayPosition = audio.SecondsPlayed
    If PlayPosition > 0 And PlayPosition < TotalLength Then
        TrackBar1.Value = (PlayPosition / TotalLength) * TotalLength
    End If
```